# Black screen with SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I was following a tutorial on building a "Pop the lock type" game and when I go to run it in the simulator a black screen shows up. I looked the up before and tried to reset the simulator and restart the computer but it doesn't work can someone please help me and tell me why this happens

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var Circle = SKSpriteNode()
var Person = SKSpriteNode()
var Dot = SKSpriteNode()

var Path = UIBezierPath()

var gameStarted = Bool()

var movingClockwise = Bool()
var intersected = false


var LevelLabel = UILabel()

    var currentLevel = Int()
    var currentScore = Int()
    var highLevel = Int()

    var View1 = UIView()
    var View2 = UIView()

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let Defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() as NSUserDefaults!
        if Defaults.integerForKey("HighLevel") != 0{
            highLevel = Defaults.integerForKey("HighLevel") as Int!
            currentLevel = highLevel
            currentScore = currentLevel
            LevelLabel.text = "\(currentScore)"
}
        else{

            Defaults.setInteger(1, forKey: "HighLevel")
}

        View1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 + 120, y: self.frame.height / 2), size: CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)))
        View1.addSubview(view)







    }

    func loadView(){
        movingClockwise = true
        backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        Circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
        Circle.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        Circle.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        self.addChild(Circle)

        Person = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Person")
        Person.size = CGSize(width: 40, height: 7)
        Person.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 + 120)
        Person.zRotation = 3.14 / 2
        Person.zPosition = 2.0
        self.addChild(Person)
        AddDot()


        LevelLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))
        LevelLabel.center = (self.view?.center)!
        LevelLabel.text = "\(currentScore)"
        LevelLabel.textColor = SKColor.darkGrayColor()
        LevelLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        LevelLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(60)
        self.View1.addSubview(LevelLabel)


    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if gameStarted == false{
            moveClockWise()
            movingClockwise = true
            gameStarted = true
        }
        else if gameStarted == true{

            if movingClockwise == true{

                moveCounterClockWise()
                movingClockwise = false
            }
            else if movingClockwise == false{

                moveClockWise()
                movingClockwise = true
            }
            DotTouched()
        }



    }



    func AddDot(){

        Dot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Dot")
        Dot.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        Dot.zPosition = 1.0

        let dx = Person.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
        let dy = Person.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

        let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

        if movingClockwise == true{
            let tempAngle = CGFloat.random(min: rad - 1.0, max: rad - 2.5)
            let Path2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 120, startAngle: tempAngle, endAngle: tempAngle + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
            Dot.position = Path2.currentPoint

        }
        else if movingClockwise == false{
            let tempAngle = CGFloat.random(min: rad + 1.0, max: rad + 2.5)
            let Path2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 120, startAngle: tempAngle, endAngle: tempAngle + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
            Dot.position = Path2.currentPoint


        }
        self.addChild(Dot)


    }


    func moveClockWise(){

        let dx = Person.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
        let dy = Person.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

        let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

        Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 120, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
        let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
        Person.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow).reversedAction())

    }

    func moveCounterClockWise(){

        let dx = Person.position.x - self.frame.width / 2
        let dy = Person.position.y - self.frame.height / 2

        let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

        Path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2), radius: 120, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
        let follow = SKAction.followPath(Path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
        Person.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))


    }

    func DotTouched(){
        if intersected == true{
            Dot.removeFromParent()
            AddDot()
            intersected = false

            currentScore--
            LevelLabel.text = "\(currentScore)"
            if currentScore <= 0{
                nextLevel()

            }

        }
        else if intersected == false{

            died()
        }

    }

    func nextLevel(){
        currentLevel++
        currentScore = currentLevel
        LevelLabel.text  = "\(currentScore)"
        won()
        if currentLevel > highLevel{
            highLevel = currentLevel
            let Defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            Defaults.setInteger(highLevel, forKey: "HighLevel")
        }


    }



    func died(){
        self.removeAllChildren()
        let action1 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.2)
        let action2 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.2)
        self.scene?.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action1,action2]))
        intersected = false
        gameStarted = false
        LevelLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        currentScore = currentLevel
        self.loadView()


    }
    func won(){
        self.removeAllChildren()
        let action1 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.greenColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.2)
        let action2 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 0.2)
        self.scene?.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action1,action2]))
        intersected = false
        gameStarted = false
        LevelLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        self.loadView()


    }



    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

        if Person.intersectsNode(Dot){
            intersected = true

        }
        else{
            if intersected == true{
                if Person.intersectsNode(Dot) == false{
                    died()
                }

            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the view controller that you have checked off initial view controller for the first view controller in storyboard?

Comment: Are you animating the view anywhere?

Comment: @mn1 what does that mean i just started doing this

Comment: Ok so when I removed the view1.addSubview(view) in didMoveToView. It worked. I clicked on the app and although I dont have the image there was something moving clockwise and had to click at the right moment.

Comment: @mn1  ok i will try it thank you

Comment: @mn1 but what do i replace did to view with

Comment: @mn1 if i remove it it works now but my images wont show and the UI text are gone

Comment: Try adding self.view?.addSubview(View1) instead.

Comment: Haha np. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @mn1 too bad i cant upvote a comment

Comment: @mn1, please add your comment as an answer, so that Kevin can approve it and the question will show as closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `View1.addSubview(view)` with `self.view?.addSubview(View1)`